# Plotting ttest with brackets in boxplot (not working with facet variable)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am using below code which is working fine and plots p-value significance but when I uncomment "facet_grid" statement then it is not plotting p-value significance. Is that a bug?

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

# Generate sample data
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  X = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 10),
  Y = rep(c("D", "E", "F"), each = 10),
  Z = rep(c("G", "H", "I"), each = 10),
  value = c(rnorm(30, mean = 5), rnorm(30, mean = 7), rnorm(30, mean = 9))
)

# Create the plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = X, y = value, group = X)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
#  facet_grid(~ fct_rev(Z), scales = "free", space = "free") +
  stat_compare_means(
    method = "t.test",
    comparisons = list(c("A", "B"), c("A", "C"), c("B", "C")),
    label = "p.signif",
    size = 3
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.3, 0.3)))

# Print the plot
print(p)
```

[image]

**PLEASE SEE UPDATED CODE TO REFLECT EXACT SCENARIO (values on X axis are not consistent across facet variable)**

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

# Generate sample data
set.seed(123)
data1 <- data.frame(
  X = rep(c("A xx", "B yy", "C zz"), each = 10),
  Z = rep(c("G"), 10),
  value = c(rnorm(30, mean = 5), rnorm(30, mean = 7), rnorm(30, mean = 9))
)

data2 <- data.frame(
  X = rep(c("A pp", "B qq", "C rr"), each = 10),
  Z = rep(c("H"), 10),
  value = c(rnorm(30, mean = 5), rnorm(30, mean = 7), rnorm(30, mean = 9))
)

data3 <- data.frame(
  X = rep(c("A xx", "B ee", "C ff"), each = 10),
  Z = rep(c("I"), 10),
  value = c(rnorm(30, mean = 5), rnorm(30, mean = 7), rnorm(30, mean = 9))
)

data <- rbind(data1, data2, data3)

# Create the plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = X, y = value, group = X)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(~ fct_rev(Z), scales = "free", space = "free") +
  stat_compare_means(
    method = "t.test",
    comparisons = list(c("A xx", "B"), c("A", "C"), c("B", "C")),
    label = "p.signif",
    size = 3
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.3, 0.3)))

# Print the plot
print(p)
```

Comment: No, it looks like in your data frame the variable `Z` changes levels with the levels of `X`, so in each facet there is only one value of `X` and it has nothing to compare. In your example data frame try changing from `Z = rep(c("G", "H", "I"), each = 10)` to `Z = rep(c("G", "H", "I"), 10)`, and you should get a result.

Comment: Try `table(data$X, data$Z)` and you will see why it cannot display 3 groups in each facet level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your X variable is completely coincident with your Z. If you facet by Z, there will only be one level of X in each facet, so there cannot be any comparisons between levels of Z in any of the facets. If you change so that your faceting variable is different from your X variable, everything works just fine:

```r
library(ggpubr)
library(tidyverse)

# Generate sample data
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  X = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 10),
  Y = rep(c("D", "E", "F"), each = 10),
  Z = rep(c("G", "H", "I"), 10),
  value = c(rnorm(30, mean = 5), rnorm(30, mean = 7), rnorm(30, mean = 9))
)

# Create the plot
ggplot(data, aes(x = X, y = value, group = X)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(~ fct_rev(Z), scales = "free", space = "free") +
  stat_compare_means(
    method = "t.test",
    comparisons = list(c("A", "B"), c("A", "C"), c("B", "C")),
    label = "p.signif",
    size = 3
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.3, 0.3)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks..sorry I updated code to reflect exact scenario of my data where p-values are not getting displayed.

Comment: @R007 but again, each level of X only appears once in each facet, and you are asking for comparisons between levels called `A` and `B` and `C` which don't exist in your data (The levels may _begin_ with these letters, but that's not enough for `ggplot` to work with)

Comment: Thanks Allan, is there any way I can build list by facet value for comparison e.g. comparisons <- list(I=c("A xx", "B yy", "C zz"), H=c("A pp", "B qq", "C rr"), G=c("A xx", "B ee", "C ff")). I want ttest to be plotted for boxes within each facet value i.e. I, H, G

Comment: @R007 you really need to have the same x axis values in each facet to do this. That is really what facets are for. What you are describing is essentially three different plots (one for each of the levels in Z). Why not just have three plots and put them side-by-side with `patchwork`?

Comment: Thats true. I have situation where I need to add "n=count" as suffix to facet value. I can use patchwork but it will be stitching too many plots manually (i.e. I need to generated 20 plot so it will be 40 plots and then add those into patch work). Just wondering if there is way manually calculate p-value and then plot it using manual method.